# How to change imagesource UWP

Tags: c#, image, uwp

I have an empty `Image`, and I want it to change it's source by full path. I tryed this, but didn't worked:

```
prev.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pathes[0].Path, UriKind.Absolute));
```

The `Image` looks like this:

```
 <Image x:Name="prev" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="303" Margin="0,47,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="219"/>
```

Comment: please provide example of `pathes[0].Path`

Comment: The application may not have read access to the image file. See [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: `"D:\\onedrive\\D képek\\BG\\312fff2a0b6924ea23d954345a499189.png"`

Comment: You can't access files directly by their path in UWP - the app doesn't have privileges for that.

Comment: Then how could I solve this?

Comment: What the type of `path[0]`?

Comment: `StorageFile`, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to setup image source from `StorageFile`, you should use following code:

```
using (var imageStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(imageStream);
    prev.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```